# Way to test if a string is valid identifier name in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, identifier

What's the most reliable way to test if a string can pass for correct variable name? 
I have couple of solutions on my mind, but I'm not quite sure which one to use:

```
// using <iframe> helper
// assuming I have hidden <iframe> inserted in document.body{}:
var _hidden_iframe_id = "iframe"+ Date.now();
var _fr = document.createElement("iframe");

_fr.setAttribute("id", _hidden_iframe_id);
_fr.setAttribute("name", _hidden_iframe_id);
_fr.style.display = "none";

document.body.appendChild(_fr);


// and .eval()-ing a string as a variable in <iframe>'s .contentWindow{}:

String.prototype.isidentifier = (function (owns, _frames, rnd, ifr_name) {

  // use private cache to save evaluated results
  var cache = {};

  // main
  return function () {

    // guard against code alike strings
    // takes everything up to left paren '(', inclusive
    var _varname = this.match(/^([^\(]*\(?)/)[1];
    var res, _win, _varval, _code;


    // been there?
    if (owns(cache, _varname)) 
      return cache[_varname];


    // flag
    res     = false;

    // random string to set as value 
    // of '_varname' in helper <iframe>
    _varval = ''+ rnd();


    try {


      // eval the iife in _win's context setting it's
      // return value to global `foo` variable. if it matches 
      // '_varvalue', the string can be used in `var` statement


      _code = 
        "foo = (function () {var "+ _varname + 
        " = '"+ _varval +"'; return "+ _varname + ";})();";

      _win = _frames[ifr_name];
      _win.eval(_code);


      // success?

      res = (_win.foo == _varval);

    } catch (e) {}


    // save the String 'varname' => Bool 'identifier-status'
    // mapping for future use

    return cache[_varname] = res;

  };

})(
  Function.prototype.call.bind(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty), 
  window.frames, 
  Math.random, 
  _hidden_iframe_id
);


//
// ---
// or something like this, using RegExp:

String.prototype.isidentifier = function () {
  return (/^[a-z_\$][\w\$]*$/i).test(this);
};

// ?
//
```

I figure regex way would be the safest (and faster?) one, but actualy trying to initialize a variable and check if it has been set correctly would be more reliable (and insecure?) way to do it, right?

---

**@SomeKittens Ux2666** Hey I've actually reproduced the regex you've posted using the 'ifame-version-function': runned it on each character in `\u0000-\uffff` range checking if it can be used as first character in variable name (yielded the exact set of characters as part of original regex where it checks the 1st character, ~48k characters), then did the same once again this time checking which characters can be used after 1st one (set first char to string `a` and looped through the character range appending each one to **a** and running the function on that...). Yielded ~50k characters, and more character points after `...\uff3f]*$/` original regex (supposed  to check remaining part of variable string). Also expanded 'reserved-words-check' part according to [ReservedWords@MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words) docs.

Here's the modified regex: (9822 characters long)

```
/^(?!(?:abstract|boolean|break|byte|case|catch|char|class|const|continue|debugger|default|delete|do|double|else|enum|export|extends|final|finally|float|for|function|goto|if|implements|import|in|instanceof|int|interface|let|long|native|new|package|private|protected|public|return|short|static|super|switch|synchronized|this|throw|throws|transient|try|typeof|var|void|volatile|while|with|yield)$)[\x24\x41-\x5A\x5F\x61-\x7A\xAA\xB5\xBA\xC0-\xD6\xD8-\xF6\xF8-\u02C1\u02C6-\u02D1\u02E0-\u02E4\u02EC\u02EE\u0370-\u0374\u0376-\u0377\u037A-\u037D\u0386\u0388-\u038A\u038C\u038E-\u03A1\u03A3-\u03F5\u03F7-\u0481\u048A-\u0527\u0531-\u0556\u0559\u0561-\u0587\u05D0-\u05EA\u05F0-\u05F2\u0620-\u064A\u066E-\u066F\u0671-\u06D3\u06D5\u06E5-\u06E6\u06EE-\u06EF\u06FA-\u06FC\u06FF\u0710\u0712-\u072F\u074D-\u07A5\u07B1\u07CA-\u07EA\u07F4-\u07F5\u07FA\u0800-\u0815\u081A\u0824\u0828\u0840-\u0858\u08A0\u08A2-\u08AC\u0904-\u0939\u093D\u0950\u0958-\u0961\u0971-\u0977\u0979-\u097F\u0985-\u098C\u098F-\u0990\u0993-\u09A8\u09AA-\u09B0\u09B2\u09B6-\u09B9\u09BD\u09CE\u09DC-\u09DD\u09DF-\u09E1\u09F0-\u09F1\u0A05-\u0A0A\u0A0F-\u0A10\u0A13-\u0A28\u0A2A-\u0A30\u0A32-\u0A33\u0A35-\u0A36\u0A38-\u0A39\u0A59-\u0A5C\u0A5E\u0A72-\u0A74\u0A85-\u0A8D\u0A8F-\u0A91\u0A93-\u0AA8\u0AAA-\u0AB0\u0AB2-\u0AB3\u0AB5-\u0AB9\u0ABD\u0AD0\u0AE0-\u0AE1\u0B05-\u0B0C\u0B0F-\u0B10\u0B13-\u0B28\u0B2A-\u0B30\u0B32-\u0B33\u0B35-\u0B39\u0B3D\u0B5C-\u0B5D\u0B5F-\u0B61\u0B71\u0B83\u0B85-\u0B8A\u0B8E-\u0B90\u0B92-\u0B95\u0B99-\u0B9A\u0B9C\u0B9E-\u0B9F\u0BA3-\u0BA4\u0BA8-\u0BAA\u0BAE-\u0BB9\u0BD0\u0C05-\u0C0C\u0C0E-\u0C10\u0C12-\u0C28\u0C2A-\u0C33\u0C35-\u0C39\u0C3D\u0C58-\u0C59\u0C60-\u0C61\u0C85-\u0C8C\u0C8E-\u0C90\u0C92-\u0CA8\u0CAA-\u0CB3\u0CB5-\u0CB9\u0CBD\u0CDE\u0CE0-\u0CE1\u0CF1-\u0CF2\u0D05-\u0D0C\u0D0E-\u0D10\u0D12-\u0D3A\u0D3D\u0D4E\u0D60-\u0D61\u0D7A-\u0D7F\u0D85-\u0D96\u0D9A-\u0DB1\u0DB3-\u0DBB\u0DBD\u0DC0-\u0DC6\u0E01-\u0E30\u0E32-\u0E33\u0E40-\u0E46\u0E81-\u0E82\u0E84\u0E87-\u0E88\u0E8A\u0E8D\u0E94-\u0E97\u0E99-\u0E9F\u0EA1-\u0EA3\u0EA5\u0EA7\u0EAA-\u0EAB\u0EAD-\u0EB0\u0EB2-\u0EB3\u0EBD\u0EC0-\u0EC4\u0EC6\u0EDC-\u0EDF\u0F00\u0F40-\u0F47\u0F49-\u0F6C\u0F88-\u0F8C\u1000-\u102A\u103F\u1050-\u1055\u105A-\u105D\u1061\u1065-\u1066\u106E-\u1070\u1075-\u1081\u108E\u10A0-\u10C5\u10C7\u10CD\u10D0-\u10FA\u10FC-\u1248\u124A-\u124D\u1250-\u1256\u1258\u125A-\u125D\u1260-\u1288\u128A-\u128D\u1290-\u12B0\u12B2-\u12B5\u12B8-\u12BE\u12C0\u12C2-\u12C5\u12C8-\u12D6\u12D8-\u1310\u1312-\u1315\u1318-\u135A\u1380-\u138F\u13A0-\u13F4\u1401-\u166C\u166F-\u167F\u1681-\u169A\u16A0-\u16EA\u16EE-\u16F0\u1700-\u170C\u170E-\u1711\u1720-\u1731\u1740-\u1751\u1760-\u176C\u176E-\u1770\u1780-\u17B3\u17D7\u17DC\u1820-\u1877\u1880-\u18A8\u18AA\u18B0-\u18F5\u1900-\u191C\u1950-\u196D\u1970-\u1974\u1980-\u19AB\u19C1-\u19C7\u1A00-\u1A16\u1A20-\u1A54\u1AA7\u1B05-\u1B33\u1B45-\u1B4B\u1B83-\u1BA0\u1BAE-\u1BAF\u1BBA-\u1BE5\u1C00-\u1C23\u1C4D-\u1C4F\u1C5A-\u1C7D\u1CE9-\u1CEC\u1CEE-\u1CF1\u1CF5-\u1CF6\u1D00-\u1DBF\u1E00-\u1F15\u1F18-\u1F1D\u1F20-\u1F45\u1F48-\u1F4D\u1F50-\u1F57\u1F59\u1F5B\u1F5D\u1F5F-\u1F7D\u1F80-\u1FB4\u1FB6-\u1FBC\u1FBE\u1FC2-\u1FC4\u1FC6-\u1FCC\u1FD0-\u1FD3\u1FD6-\u1FDB\u1FE0-\u1FEC\u1FF2-\u1FF4\u1FF6-\u1FFC\u2071\u207F\u2090-\u209C\u2102\u2107\u210A-\u2113\u2115\u2119-\u211D\u2124\u2126\u2128\u212A-\u212D\u212F-\u2139\u213C-\u213F\u2145-\u2149\u214E\u2160-\u2188\u2C00-\u2C2E\u2C30-\u2C5E\u2C60-\u2CE4\u2CEB-\u2CEE\u2CF2-\u2CF3\u2D00-\u2D25\u2D27\u2D2D\u2D30-\u2D67\u2D6F\u2D80-\u2D96\u2DA0-\u2DA6\u2DA8-\u2DAE\u2DB0-\u2DB6\u2DB8-\u2DBE\u2DC0-\u2DC6\u2DC8-\u2DCE\u2DD0-\u2DD6\u2DD8-\u2DDE\u2E2F\u3005-\u3007\u3021-\u3029\u3031-\u3035\u3038-\u303C\u3041-\u3096\u309D-\u309F\u30A1-\u30FA\u30FC-\u30FF\u3105-\u312D\u3131-\u318E\u31A0-\u31BA\u31F0-\u31FF\u3400-\u4DB5\u4E00-\u9FCC\uA000-\uA48C\uA4D0-\uA4FD\uA500-\uA60C\uA610-\uA61F\uA62A-\uA62B\uA640-\uA66E\uA67F-\uA697\uA6A0-\uA6EF\uA717-\uA71F\uA722-\uA788\uA78B-\uA78E\uA790-\uA793\uA7A0-\uA7AA\uA7F8-\uA801\uA803-\uA805\uA807-\uA80A\uA80C-\uA822\uA840-\uA873\uA882-\uA8B3\uA8F2-\uA8F7\uA8FB\uA90A-\uA925\uA930-\uA946\uA960-\uA97C\uA984-\uA9B2\uA9CF\uAA00-\uAA28\uAA40-\uAA42\uAA44-\uAA4B\uAA60-\uAA76\uAA7A\uAA80-\uAAAF\uAAB1\uAAB5-\uAAB6\uAAB9-\uAABD\uAAC0\uAAC2\uAADB-\uAADD\uAAE0-\uAAEA\uAAF2-\uAAF4\uAB01-\uAB06\uAB09-\uAB0E\uAB11-\uAB16\uAB20-\uAB26\uAB28-\uAB2E\uABC0-\uABE2\uAC00-\uD7A3\uD7B0-\uD7C6\uD7CB-\uD7FB\uF900-\uFA6D\uFA70-\uFAD9\uFB00-\uFB06\uFB13-\uFB17\uFB1D\uFB1F-\uFB28\uFB2A-\uFB36\uFB38-\uFB3C\uFB3E\uFB40-\uFB41\uFB43-\uFB44\uFB46-\uFBB1\uFBD3-\uFD3D\uFD50-\uFD8F\uFD92-\uFDC7\uFDF0-\uFDFB\uFE70-\uFE74\uFE76-\uFEFC\uFF21-\uFF3A\uFF41-\uFF5A\uFF66-\uFFBE\uFFC2-\uFFC7\uFFCA-\uFFCF\uFFD2-\uFFD7\uFFDA-\uFFDC][\x24\x30-\x39\x41-\x5A\x5F\x61-\x7A\xA0\xAA\xB5\xBA\xC0-\xD6\xD8-\xF6\xF8-\u02C1\u02C6-\u02D1\u02E0-\u02E4\u02EC\u02EE\u0300-\u0374\u0376-\u0377\u037A-\u037D\u0386\u0388-\u038A\u038C\u038E-\u03A1\u03A3-\u03F5\u03F7-\u0481\u0483-\u0487\u048A-\u0527\u0531-\u0556\u0559\u0561-\u0587\u0591-\u05BD\u05BF\u05C1-\u05C2\u05C4-\u05C5\u05C7\u05D0-\u05EA\u05F0-\u05F2\u0610-\u061A\u0620-\u0669\u066E-\u06D3\u06D5-\u06DC\u06DF-\u06E8\u06EA-\u06FC\u06FF\u0710-\u074A\u074D-\u07B1\u07C0-\u07F5\u07FA\u0800-\u082D\u0840-\u085B\u08A0\u08A2-\u08AC\u08E4-\u08FE\u0900-\u0963\u0966-\u096F\u0971-\u0977\u0979-\u097F\u0981-\u0983\u0985-\u098C\u098F-\u0990\u0993-\u09A8\u09AA-\u09B0\u09B2\u09B6-\u09B9\u09BC-\u09C4\u09C7-\u09C8\u09CB-\u09CE\u09D7\u09DC-\u09DD\u09DF-\u09E3\u09E6-\u09F1\u0A01-\u0A03\u0A05-\u0A0A\u0A0F-\u0A10\u0A13-\u0A28\u0A2A-\u0A30\u0A32-\u0A33\u0A35-\u0A36\u0A38-\u0A39\u0A3C\u0A3E-\u0A42\u0A47-\u0A48\u0A4B-\u0A4D\u0A51\u0A59-\u0A5C\u0A5E\u0A66-\u0A75\u0A81-\u0A83\u0A85-\u0A8D\u0A8F-\u0A91\u0A93-\u0AA8\u0AAA-\u0AB0\u0AB2-\u0AB3\u0AB5-\u0AB9\u0ABC-\u0AC5\u0AC7-\u0AC9\u0ACB-\u0ACD\u0AD0\u0AE0-\u0AE3\u0AE6-\u0AEF\u0B01-\u0B03\u0B05-\u0B0C\u0B0F-\u0B10\u0B13-\u0B28\u0B2A-\u0B30\u0B32-\u0B33\u0B35-\u0B39\u0B3C-\u0B44\u0B47-\u0B48\u0B4B-\u0B4D\u0B56-\u0B57\u0B5C-\u0B5D\u0B5F-\u0B63\u0B66-\u0B6F\u0B71\u0B82-\u0B83\u0B85-\u0B8A\u0B8E-\u0B90\u0B92-\u0B95\u0B99-\u0B9A\u0B9C\u0B9E-\u0B9F\u0BA3-\u0BA4\u0BA8-\u0BAA\u0BAE-\u0BB9\u0BBE-\u0BC2\u0BC6-\u0BC8\u0BCA-\u0BCD\u0BD0\u0BD7\u0BE6-\u0BEF\u0C01-\u0C03\u0C05-\u0C0C\u0C0E-\u0C10\u0C12-\u0C28\u0C2A-\u0C33\u0C35-\u0C39\u0C3D-\u0C44\u0C46-\u0C48\u0C4A-\u0C4D\u0C55-\u0C56\u0C58-\u0C59\u0C60-\u0C63\u0C66-\u0C6F\u0C82-\u0C83\u0C85-\u0C8C\u0C8E-\u0C90\u0C92-\u0CA8\u0CAA-\u0CB3\u0CB5-\u0CB9\u0CBC-\u0CC4\u0CC6-\u0CC8\u0CCA-\u0CCD\u0CD5-\u0CD6\u0CDE\u0CE0-\u0CE3\u0CE6-\u0CEF\u0CF1-\u0CF2\u0D02-\u0D03\u0D05-\u0D0C\u0D0E-\u0D10\u0D12-\u0D3A\u0D3D-\u0D44\u0D46-\u0D48\u0D4A-\u0D4E\u0D57\u0D60-\u0D63\u0D66-\u0D6F\u0D7A-\u0D7F\u0D82-\u0D83\u0D85-\u0D96\u0D9A-\u0DB1\u0DB3-\u0DBB\u0DBD\u0DC0-\u0DC6\u0DCA\u0DCF-\u0DD4\u0DD6\u0DD8-\u0DDF\u0DF2-\u0DF3\u0E01-\u0E3A\u0E40-\u0E4E\u0E50-\u0E59\u0E81-\u0E82\u0E84\u0E87-\u0E88\u0E8A\u0E8D\u0E94-\u0E97\u0E99-\u0E9F\u0EA1-\u0EA3\u0EA5\u0EA7\u0EAA-\u0EAB\u0EAD-\u0EB9\u0EBB-\u0EBD\u0EC0-\u0EC4\u0EC6\u0EC8-\u0ECD\u0ED0-\u0ED9\u0EDC-\u0EDF\u0F00\u0F18-\u0F19\u0F20-\u0F29\u0F35\u0F37\u0F39\u0F3E-\u0F47\u0F49-\u0F6C\u0F71-\u0F84\u0F86-\u0F97\u0F99-\u0FBC\u0FC6\u1000-\u1049\u1050-\u109D\u10A0-\u10C5\u10C7\u10CD\u10D0-\u10FA\u10FC-\u1248\u124A-\u124D\u1250-\u1256\u1258\u125A-\u125D\u1260-\u1288\u128A-\u128D\u1290-\u12B0\u12B2-\u12B5\u12B8-\u12BE\u12C0\u12C2-\u12C5\u12C8-\u12D6\u12D8-\u1310\u1312-\u1315\u1318-\u135A\u135D-\u135F\u1380-\u138F\u13A0-\u13F4\u1401-\u166C\u166F-\u169A\u16A0-\u16EA\u16EE-\u16F0\u1700-\u170C\u170E-\u1714\u1720-\u1734\u1740-\u1753\u1760-\u176C\u176E-\u1770\u1772-\u1773\u1780-\u17D3\u17D7\u17DC-\u17DD\u17E0-\u17E9\u180B-\u180E\u1810-\u1819\u1820-\u1877\u1880-\u18AA\u18B0-\u18F5\u1900-\u191C\u1920-\u192B\u1930-\u193B\u1946-\u196D\u1970-\u1974\u1980-\u19AB\u19B0-\u19C9\u19D0-\u19D9\u1A00-\u1A1B\u1A20-\u1A5E\u1A60-\u1A7C\u1A7F-\u1A89\u1A90-\u1A99\u1AA7\u1B00-\u1B4B\u1B50-\u1B59\u1B6B-\u1B73\u1B80-\u1BF3\u1C00-\u1C37\u1C40-\u1C49\u1C4D-\u1C7D\u1CD0-\u1CD2\u1CD4-\u1CF6\u1D00-\u1DE6\u1DFC-\u1F15\u1F18-\u1F1D\u1F20-\u1F45\u1F48-\u1F4D\u1F50-\u1F57\u1F59\u1F5B\u1F5D\u1F5F-\u1F7D\u1F80-\u1FB4\u1FB6-\u1FBC\u1FBE\u1FC2-\u1FC4\u1FC6-\u1FCC\u1FD0-\u1FD3\u1FD6-\u1FDB\u1FE0-\u1FEC\u1FF2-\u1FF4\u1FF6-\u1FFC\u2000-\u200A\u200C-\u200D\u2028-\u2029\u202F\u203F-\u2040\u2054\u205F\u2071\u207F\u2090-\u209C\u20D0-\u20DC\u20E1\u20E5-\u20F0\u2102\u2107\u210A-\u2113\u2115\u2119-\u211D\u2124\u2126\u2128\u212A-\u212D\u212F-\u2139\u213C-\u213F\u2145-\u2149\u214E\u2160-\u2188\u2C00-\u2C2E\u2C30-\u2C5E\u2C60-\u2CE4\u2CEB-\u2CF3\u2D00-\u2D25\u2D27\u2D2D\u2D30-\u2D67\u2D6F\u2D7F-\u2D96\u2DA0-\u2DA6\u2DA8-\u2DAE\u2DB0-\u2DB6\u2DB8-\u2DBE\u2DC0-\u2DC6\u2DC8-\u2DCE\u2DD0-\u2DD6\u2DD8-\u2DDE\u2DE0-\u2DFF\u2E2F\u3000\u3005-\u3007\u3021-\u302F\u3031-\u3035\u3038-\u303C\u3041-\u3096\u3099-\u309A\u309D-\u309F\u30A1-\u30FA\u30FC-\u30FF\u3105-\u312D\u3131-\u318E\u31A0-\u31BA\u31F0-\u31FF\u3400-\u4DB5\u4E00-\u9FCC\uA000-\uA48C\uA4D0-\uA4FD\uA500-\uA60C\uA610-\uA62B\uA640-\uA66F\uA674-\uA67D\uA67F-\uA697\uA69F-\uA6F1\uA717-\uA71F\uA722-\uA788\uA78B-\uA78E\uA790-\uA793\uA7A0-\uA7AA\uA7F8-\uA827\uA840-\uA873\uA880-\uA8C4\uA8D0-\uA8D9\uA8E0-\uA8F7\uA8FB\uA900-\uA92D\uA930-\uA953\uA960-\uA97C\uA980-\uA9C0\uA9CF-\uA9D9\uAA00-\uAA36\uAA40-\uAA4D\uAA50-\uAA59\uAA60-\uAA76\uAA7A-\uAA7B\uAA80-\uAAC2\uAADB-\uAADD\uAAE0-\uAAEF\uAAF2-\uAAF6\uAB01-\uAB06\uAB09-\uAB0E\uAB11-\uAB16\uAB20-\uAB26\uAB28-\uAB2E\uABC0-\uABEA\uABEC-\uABED\uABF0-\uABF9\uAC00-\uD7A3\uD7B0-\uD7C6\uD7CB-\uD7FB\uF900-\uFA6D\uFA70-\uFAD9\uFB00-\uFB06\uFB13-\uFB17\uFB1D-\uFB28\uFB2A-\uFB36\uFB38-\uFB3C\uFB3E\uFB40-\uFB41\uFB43-\uFB44\uFB46-\uFBB1\uFBD3-\uFD3D\uFD50-\uFD8F\uFD92-\uFDC7\uFDF0-\uFDFB\uFE00-\uFE0F\uFE20-\uFE26\uFE33-\uFE34\uFE4D-\uFE4F\uFE70-\uFE74\uFE76-\uFEFC\uFEFF\uFF10-\uFF19\uFF21-\uFF3A\uFF3F\uFF41-\uFF5A\uFF66-\uFFBE\uFFC2-\uFFC7\uFFCA-\uFFCF\uFFD2-\uFFD7\uFFDA-\uFFDC\uFFFE]*$/

//
```

Comment: Its probably not necessary to do this, you can just use this[kind][of][notation]

Comment: and I can do: `this["?!"] = 1;`, but `?!` can not be used with `var ...` statement...

Comment: @nikolav yes, that is correct

Comment: As an alternative to regular expressions, the referenced ("duplicate") question contains answers that are based on *eval* in a try-catch-block to "ask the browser if the name is valid".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In one 'simple' regex:

```
/^(?!(?:do|if|in|for|let|new|try|var|case|else|enum|eval|false|null|this|true|void|with|break|catch|class|const|super|throw|while|yield|delete|export|import|public|return|static|switch|typeof|default|extends|finally|package|private|continue|debugger|function|arguments|interface|protected|implements|instanceof)$)[$A-Z\_a-z\xaa\xb5\xba\xc0-\xd6\xd8-\xf6\xf8-\u02c1\u02c6-\u02d1\u02e0-\u02e4\u02ec\u02ee\u0370-\u0374\u0376\u0377\u037a-\u037d\u0386\u0388-\u038a\u038c\u038e-\u03a1\u03a3-\u03f5\u03f7-\u0481\u048a-\u0527\u0531-\u0556\u0559\u0561-\u0587\u05d0-\u05ea\u05f0-\u05f2\u0620-\u064a\u066e\u066f\u0671-\u06d3\u06d5\u06e5\u06e6\u06ee\u06ef\u06fa-\u06fc\u06ff\u0710\u0712-\u072f\u074d-\u07a5\u07b1\u07ca-\u07ea\u07f4\u07f5\u07fa\u0800-\u0815\u081a\u0824\u0828\u0840-\u0858\u08a0\u08a2-\u08ac\u0904-\u0939\u093d\u0950\u0958-\u0961\u0971-\u0977\u0979-\u097f\u0985-\u098c\u098f\u0990\u0993-\u09a8\u09aa-\u09b0\u09b2\u09b6-\u09b9\u09bd\u09ce\u09dc\u09dd\u09df-\u09e1\u09f0\u09f1\u0a05-\u0a0a\u0a0f\u0a10\u0a13-\u0a28\u0a2a-\u0a30\u0a32\u0a33\u0a35\u0a36\u0a38\u0a39\u0a59-\u0a5c\u0a5e\u0a72-\u0a74\u0a85-\u0a8d\u0a8f-\u0a91\u0a93-\u0aa8\u0aaa-\u0ab0\u0ab2\u0ab3\u0ab5-\u0ab9\u0abd\u0ad0\u0ae0\u0ae1\u0b05-\u0b0c\u0b0f\u0b10\u0b13-\u0b28\u0b2a-\u0b30\u0b32\u0b33\u0b35-\u0b39\u0b3d\u0b5c\u0b5d\u0b5f-\u0b61\u0b71\u0b83\u0b85-\u0b8a\u0b8e-\u0b90\u0b92-\u0b95\u0b99\u0b9a\u0b9c\u0b9e\u0b9f\u0ba3\u0ba4\u0ba8-\u0baa\u0bae-\u0bb9\u0bd0\u0c05-\u0c0c\u0c0e-\u0c10\u0c12-\u0c28\u0c2a-\u0c33\u0c35-\u0c39\u0c3d\u0c58\u0c59\u0c60\u0c61\u0c85-\u0c8c\u0c8e-\u0c90\u0c92-\u0ca8\u0caa-\u0cb3\u0cb5-\u0cb9\u0cbd\u0cde\u0ce0\u0ce1\u0cf1\u0cf2\u0d05-\u0d0c\u0d0e-\u0d10\u0d12-\u0d3a\u0d3d\u0d4e\u0d60\u0d61\u0d7a-\u0d7f\u0d85-\u0d96\u0d9a-\u0db1\u0db3-\u0dbb\u0dbd\u0dc0-\u0dc6\u0e01-\u0e30\u0e32\u0e33\u0e40-\u0e46\u0e81\u0e82\u0e84\u0e87\u0e88\u0e8a\u0e8d\u0e94-\u0e97\u0e99-\u0e9f\u0ea1-\u0ea3\u0ea5\u0ea7\u0eaa\u0eab\u0ead-\u0eb0\u0eb2\u0eb3\u0ebd\u0ec0-\u0ec4\u0ec6\u0edc-\u0edf\u0f00\u0f40-\u0f47\u0f49-\u0f6c\u0f88-\u0f8c\u1000-\u102a\u103f\u1050-\u1055\u105a-\u105d\u1061\u1065\u1066\u106e-\u1070\u1075-\u1081\u108e\u10a0-\u10c5\u10c7\u10cd\u10d0-\u10fa\u10fc-\u1248\u124a-\u124d\u1250-\u1256\u1258\u125a-\u125d\u1260-\u1288\u128a-\u128d\u1290-\u12b0\u12b2-\u12b5\u12b8-\u12be\u12c0\u12c2-\u12c5\u12c8-\u12d6\u12d8-\u1310\u1312-\u1315\u1318-\u135a\u1380-\u138f\u13a0-\u13f4\u1401-\u166c\u166f-\u167f\u1681-\u169a\u16a0-\u16ea\u16ee-\u16f0\u1700-\u170c\u170e-\u1711\u1720-\u1731\u1740-\u1751\u1760-\u176c\u176e-\u1770\u1780-\u17b3\u17d7\u17dc\u1820-\u1877\u1880-\u18a8\u18aa\u18b0-\u18f5\u1900-\u191c\u1950-\u196d\u1970-\u1974\u1980-\u19ab\u19c1-\u19c7\u1a00-\u1a16\u1a20-\u1a54\u1aa7\u1b05-\u1b33\u1b45-\u1b4b\u1b83-\u1ba0\u1bae\u1baf\u1bba-\u1be5\u1c00-\u1c23\u1c4d-\u1c4f\u1c5a-\u1c7d\u1ce9-\u1cec\u1cee-\u1cf1\u1cf5\u1cf6\u1d00-\u1dbf\u1e00-\u1f15\u1f18-\u1f1d\u1f20-\u1f45\u1f48-\u1f4d\u1f50-\u1f57\u1f59\u1f5b\u1f5d\u1f5f-\u1f7d\u1f80-\u1fb4\u1fb6-\u1fbc\u1fbe\u1fc2-\u1fc4\u1fc6-\u1fcc\u1fd0-\u1fd3\u1fd6-\u1fdb\u1fe0-\u1fec\u1ff2-\u1ff4\u1ff6-\u1ffc\u2071\u207f\u2090-\u209c\u2102\u2107\u210a-\u2113\u2115\u2119-\u211d\u2124\u2126\u2128\u212a-\u212d\u212f-\u2139\u213c-\u213f\u2145-\u2149\u214e\u2160-\u2188\u2c00-\u2c2e\u2c30-\u2c5e\u2c60-\u2ce4\u2ceb-\u2cee\u2cf2\u2cf3\u2d00-\u2d25\u2d27\u2d2d\u2d30-\u2d67\u2d6f\u2d80-\u2d96\u2da0-\u2da6\u2da8-\u2dae\u2db0-\u2db6\u2db8-\u2dbe\u2dc0-\u2dc6\u2dc8-\u2dce\u2dd0-\u2dd6\u2dd8-\u2dde\u2e2f\u3005-\u3007\u3021-\u3029\u3031-\u3035\u3038-\u303c\u3041-\u3096\u309d-\u309f\u30a1-\u30fa\u30fc-\u30ff\u3105-\u312d\u3131-\u318e\u31a0-\u31ba\u31f0-\u31ff\u3400-\u4db5\u4e00-\u9fcc\ua000-\ua48c\ua4d0-\ua4fd\ua500-\ua60c\ua610-\ua61f\ua62a\ua62b\ua640-\ua66e\ua67f-\ua697\ua6a0-\ua6ef\ua717-\ua71f\ua722-\ua788\ua78b-\ua78e\ua790-\ua793\ua7a0-\ua7aa\ua7f8-\ua801\ua803-\ua805\ua807-\ua80a\ua80c-\ua822\ua840-\ua873\ua882-\ua8b3\ua8f2-\ua8f7\ua8fb\ua90a-\ua925\ua930-\ua946\ua960-\ua97c\ua984-\ua9b2\ua9cf\uaa00-\uaa28\uaa40-\uaa42\uaa44-\uaa4b\uaa60-\uaa76\uaa7a\uaa80-\uaaaf\uaab1\uaab5\uaab6\uaab9-\uaabd\uaac0\uaac2\uaadb-\uaadd\uaae0-\uaaea\uaaf2-\uaaf4\uab01-\uab06\uab09-\uab0e\uab11-\uab16\uab20-\uab26\uab28-\uab2e\uabc0-\uabe2\uac00-\ud7a3\ud7b0-\ud7c6\ud7cb-\ud7fb\uf900-\ufa6d\ufa70-\ufad9\ufb00-\ufb06\ufb13-\ufb17\ufb1d\ufb1f-\ufb28\ufb2a-\ufb36\ufb38-\ufb3c\ufb3e\ufb40\ufb41\ufb43\ufb44\ufb46-\ufbb1\ufbd3-\ufd3d\ufd50-\ufd8f\ufd92-\ufdc7\ufdf0-\ufdfb\ufe70-\ufe74\ufe76-\ufefc\uff21-\uff3a\uff41-\uff5a\uff66-\uffbe\uffc2-\uffc7\uffca-\uffcf\uffd2-\uffd7\uffda-\uffdc][$A-Z\_a-z\xaa\xb5\xba\xc0-\xd6\xd8-\xf6\xf8-\u02c1\u02c6-\u02d1\u02e0-\u02e4\u02ec\u02ee\u0370-\u0374\u0376\u0377\u037a-\u037d\u0386\u0388-\u038a\u038c\u038e-\u03a1\u03a3-\u03f5\u03f7-\u0481\u048a-\u0527\u0531-\u0556\u0559\u0561-\u0587\u05d0-\u05ea\u05f0-\u05f2\u0620-\u064a\u066e\u066f\u0671-\u06d3\u06d5\u06e5\u06e6\u06ee\u06ef\u06fa-\u06fc\u06ff\u0710\u0712-\u072f\u074d-\u07a5\u07b1\u07ca-\u07ea\u07f4\u07f5\u07fa\u0800-\u0815\u081a\u0824\u0828\u0840-\u0858\u08a0\u08a2-\u08ac\u0904-\u0939\u093d\u0950\u0958-\u0961\u0971-\u0977\u0979-\u097f\u0985-\u098c\u098f\u0990\u0993-\u09a8\u09aa-\u09b0\u09b2\u09b6-\u09b9\u09bd\u09ce\u09dc\u09dd\u09df-\u09e1\u09f0\u09f1\u0a05-\u0a0a\u0a0f\u0a10\u0a13-\u0a28\u0a2a-\u0a30\u0a32\u0a33\u0a35\u0a36\u0a38\u0a39\u0a59-\u0a5c\u0a5e\u0a72-\u0a74\u0a85-\u0a8d\u0a8f-\u0a91\u0a93-\u0aa8\u0aaa-\u0ab0\u0ab2\u0ab3\u0ab5-\u0ab9\u0abd\u0ad0\u0ae0\u0ae1\u0b05-\u0b0c\u0b0f\u0b10\u0b13-\u0b28\u0b2a-\u0b30\u0b32\u0b33\u0b35-\u0b39\u0b3d\u0b5c\u0b5d\u0b5f-\u0b61\u0b71\u0b83\u0b85-\u0b8a\u0b8e-\u0b90\u0b92-\u0b95\u0b99\u0b9a\u0b9c\u0b9e\u0b9f\u0ba3\u0ba4\u0ba8-\u0baa\u0bae-\u0bb9\u0bd0\u0c05-\u0c0c\u0c0e-\u0c10\u0c12-\u0c28\u0c2a-\u0c33\u0c35-\u0c39\u0c3d\u0c58\u0c59\u0c60\u0c61\u0c85-\u0c8c\u0c8e-\u0c90\u0c92-\u0ca8\u0caa-\u0cb3\u0cb5-\u0cb9\u0cbd\u0cde\u0ce0\u0ce1\u0cf1\u0cf2\u0d05-\u0d0c\u0d0e-\u0d10\u0d12-\u0d3a\u0d3d\u0d4e\u0d60\u0d61\u0d7a-\u0d7f\u0d85-\u0d96\u0d9a-\u0db1\u0db3-\u0dbb\u0dbd\u0dc0-\u0dc6\u0e01-\u0e30\u0e32\u0e33\u0e40-\u0e46\u0e81\u0e82\u0e84\u0e87\u0e88\u0e8a\u0e8d\u0e94-\u0e97\u0e99-\u0e9f\u0ea1-\u0ea3\u0ea5\u0ea7\u0eaa\u0eab\u0ead-\u0eb0\u0eb2\u0eb3\u0ebd\u0ec0-\u0ec4\u0ec6\u0edc-\u0edf\u0f00\u0f40-\u0f47\u0f49-\u0f6c\u0f88-\u0f8c\u1000-\u102a\u103f\u1050-\u1055\u105a-\u105d\u1061\u1065\u1066\u106e-\u1070\u1075-\u1081\u108e\u10a0-\u10c5\u10c7\u10cd\u10d0-\u10fa\u10fc-\u1248\u124a-\u124d\u1250-\u1256\u1258\u125a-\u125d\u1260-\u1288\u128a-\u128d\u1290-\u12b0\u12b2-\u12b5\u12b8-\u12be\u12c0\u12c2-\u12c5\u12c8-\u12d6\u12d8-\u1310\u1312-\u1315\u1318-\u135a\u1380-\u138f\u13a0-\u13f4\u1401-\u166c\u166f-\u167f\u1681-\u169a\u16a0-\u16ea\u16ee-\u16f0\u1700-\u170c\u170e-\u1711\u1720-\u1731\u1740-\u1751\u1760-\u176c\u176e-\u1770\u1780-\u17b3\u17d7\u17dc\u1820-\u1877\u1880-\u18a8\u18aa\u18b0-\u18f5\u1900-\u191c\u1950-\u196d\u1970-\u1974\u1980-\u19ab\u19c1-\u19c7\u1a00-\u1a16\u1a20-\u1a54\u1aa7\u1b05-\u1b33\u1b45-\u1b4b\u1b83-\u1ba0\u1bae\u1baf\u1bba-\u1be5\u1c00-\u1c23\u1c4d-\u1c4f\u1c5a-\u1c7d\u1ce9-\u1cec\u1cee-\u1cf1\u1cf5\u1cf6\u1d00-\u1dbf\u1e00-\u1f15\u1f18-\u1f1d\u1f20-\u1f45\u1f48-\u1f4d\u1f50-\u1f57\u1f59\u1f5b\u1f5d\u1f5f-\u1f7d\u1f80-\u1fb4\u1fb6-\u1fbc\u1fbe\u1fc2-\u1fc4\u1fc6-\u1fcc\u1fd0-\u1fd3\u1fd6-\u1fdb\u1fe0-\u1fec\u1ff2-\u1ff4\u1ff6-\u1ffc\u2071\u207f\u2090-\u209c\u2102\u2107\u210a-\u2113\u2115\u2119-\u211d\u2124\u2126\u2128\u212a-\u212d\u212f-\u2139\u213c-\u213f\u2145-\u2149\u214e\u2160-\u2188\u2c00-\u2c2e\u2c30-\u2c5e\u2c60-\u2ce4\u2ceb-\u2cee\u2cf2\u2cf3\u2d00-\u2d25\u2d27\u2d2d\u2d30-\u2d67\u2d6f\u2d80-\u2d96\u2da0-\u2da6\u2da8-\u2dae\u2db0-\u2db6\u2db8-\u2dbe\u2dc0-\u2dc6\u2dc8-\u2dce\u2dd0-\u2dd6\u2dd8-\u2dde\u2e2f\u3005-\u3007\u3021-\u3029\u3031-\u3035\u3038-\u303c\u3041-\u3096\u309d-\u309f\u30a1-\u30fa\u30fc-\u30ff\u3105-\u312d\u3131-\u318e\u31a0-\u31ba\u31f0-\u31ff\u3400-\u4db5\u4e00-\u9fcc\ua000-\ua48c\ua4d0-\ua4fd\ua500-\ua60c\ua610-\ua61f\ua62a\ua62b\ua640-\ua66e\ua67f-\ua697\ua6a0-\ua6ef\ua717-\ua71f\ua722-\ua788\ua78b-\ua78e\ua790-\ua793\ua7a0-\ua7aa\ua7f8-\ua801\ua803-\ua805\ua807-\ua80a\ua80c-\ua822\ua840-\ua873\ua882-\ua8b3\ua8f2-\ua8f7\ua8fb\ua90a-\ua925\ua930-\ua946\ua960-\ua97c\ua984-\ua9b2\ua9cf\uaa00-\uaa28\uaa40-\uaa42\uaa44-\uaa4b\uaa60-\uaa76\uaa7a\uaa80-\uaaaf\uaab1\uaab5\uaab6\uaab9-\uaabd\uaac0\uaac2\uaadb-\uaadd\uaae0-\uaaea\uaaf2-\uaaf4\uab01-\uab06\uab09-\uab0e\uab11-\uab16\uab20-\uab26\uab28-\uab2e\uabc0-\uabe2\uac00-\ud7a3\ud7b0-\ud7c6\ud7cb-\ud7fb\uf900-\ufa6d\ufa70-\ufad9\ufb00-\ufb06\ufb13-\ufb17\ufb1d\ufb1f-\ufb28\ufb2a-\ufb36\ufb38-\ufb3c\ufb3e\ufb40\ufb41\ufb43\ufb44\ufb46-\ufbb1\ufbd3-\ufd3d\ufd50-\ufd8f\ufd92-\ufdc7\ufdf0-\ufdfb\ufe70-\ufe74\ufe76-\ufefc\uff21-\uff3a\uff41-\uff5a\uff66-\uffbe\uffc2-\uffc7\uffca-\uffcf\uffd2-\uffd7\uffda-\uffdc0-9\u0300-\u036f\u0483-\u0487\u0591-\u05bd\u05bf\u05c1\u05c2\u05c4\u05c5\u05c7\u0610-\u061a\u064b-\u0669\u0670\u06d6-\u06dc\u06df-\u06e4\u06e7\u06e8\u06ea-\u06ed\u06f0-\u06f9\u0711\u0730-\u074a\u07a6-\u07b0\u07c0-\u07c9\u07eb-\u07f3\u0816-\u0819\u081b-\u0823\u0825-\u0827\u0829-\u082d\u0859-\u085b\u08e4-\u08fe\u0900-\u0903\u093a-\u093c\u093e-\u094f\u0951-\u0957\u0962\u0963\u0966-\u096f\u0981-\u0983\u09bc\u09be-\u09c4\u09c7\u09c8\u09cb-\u09cd\u09d7\u09e2\u09e3\u09e6-\u09ef\u0a01-\u0a03\u0a3c\u0a3e-\u0a42\u0a47\u0a48\u0a4b-\u0a4d\u0a51\u0a66-\u0a71\u0a75\u0a81-\u0a83\u0abc\u0abe-\u0ac5\u0ac7-\u0ac9\u0acb-\u0acd\u0ae2\u0ae3\u0ae6-\u0aef\u0b01-\u0b03\u0b3c\u0b3e-\u0b44\u0b47\u0b48\u0b4b-\u0b4d\u0b56\u0b57\u0b62\u0b63\u0b66-\u0b6f\u0b82\u0bbe-\u0bc2\u0bc6-\u0bc8\u0bca-\u0bcd\u0bd7\u0be6-\u0bef\u0c01-\u0c03\u0c3e-\u0c44\u0c46-\u0c48\u0c4a-\u0c4d\u0c55\u0c56\u0c62\u0c63\u0c66-\u0c6f\u0c82\u0c83\u0cbc\u0cbe-\u0cc4\u0cc6-\u0cc8\u0cca-\u0ccd\u0cd5\u0cd6\u0ce2\u0ce3\u0ce6-\u0cef\u0d02\u0d03\u0d3e-\u0d44\u0d46-\u0d48\u0d4a-\u0d4d\u0d57\u0d62\u0d63\u0d66-\u0d6f\u0d82\u0d83\u0dca\u0dcf-\u0dd4\u0dd6\u0dd8-\u0ddf\u0df2\u0df3\u0e31\u0e34-\u0e3a\u0e47-\u0e4e\u0e50-\u0e59\u0eb1\u0eb4-\u0eb9\u0ebb\u0ebc\u0ec8-\u0ecd\u0ed0-\u0ed9\u0f18\u0f19\u0f20-\u0f29\u0f35\u0f37\u0f39\u0f3e\u0f3f\u0f71-\u0f84\u0f86\u0f87\u0f8d-\u0f97\u0f99-\u0fbc\u0fc6\u102b-\u103e\u1040-\u1049\u1056-\u1059\u105e-\u1060\u1062-\u1064\u1067-\u106d\u1071-\u1074\u1082-\u108d\u108f-\u109d\u135d-\u135f\u1712-\u1714\u1732-\u1734\u1752\u1753\u1772\u1773\u17b4-\u17d3\u17dd\u17e0-\u17e9\u180b-\u180d\u1810-\u1819\u18a9\u1920-\u192b\u1930-\u193b\u1946-\u194f\u19b0-\u19c0\u19c8\u19c9\u19d0-\u19d9\u1a17-\u1a1b\u1a55-\u1a5e\u1a60-\u1a7c\u1a7f-\u1a89\u1a90-\u1a99\u1b00-\u1b04\u1b34-\u1b44\u1b50-\u1b59\u1b6b-\u1b73\u1b80-\u1b82\u1ba1-\u1bad\u1bb0-\u1bb9\u1be6-\u1bf3\u1c24-\u1c37\u1c40-\u1c49\u1c50-\u1c59\u1cd0-\u1cd2\u1cd4-\u1ce8\u1ced\u1cf2-\u1cf4\u1dc0-\u1de6\u1dfc-\u1dff\u200c\u200d\u203f\u2040\u2054\u20d0-\u20dc\u20e1\u20e5-\u20f0\u2cef-\u2cf1\u2d7f\u2de0-\u2dff\u302a-\u302f\u3099\u309a\ua620-\ua629\ua66f\ua674-\ua67d\ua69f\ua6f0\ua6f1\ua802\ua806\ua80b\ua823-\ua827\ua880\ua881\ua8b4-\ua8c4\ua8d0-\ua8d9\ua8e0-\ua8f1\ua900-\ua909\ua926-\ua92d\ua947-\ua953\ua980-\ua983\ua9b3-\ua9c0\ua9d0-\ua9d9\uaa29-\uaa36\uaa43\uaa4c\uaa4d\uaa50-\uaa59\uaa7b\uaab0\uaab2-\uaab4\uaab7\uaab8\uaabe\uaabf\uaac1\uaaeb-\uaaef\uaaf5\uaaf6\uabe3-\uabea\uabec\uabed\uabf0-\uabf9\ufb1e\ufe00-\ufe0f\ufe20-\ufe26\ufe33\ufe34\ufe4d-\ufe4f\uff10-\uff19\uff3f]*$/
```

Yeah, not quite.  The problem arises from the fact that *so many* characters are perfectly legal:

> An identifier must start with `$`, `_`, or any character in the Unicode categories [“Uppercase letter (Lu)”](http://graphemica.com/categories/uppercase-letter), [“Lowercase letter (Ll)”](http://graphemica.com/categories/lowercase-letter), [“Titlecase letter (Lt)”](http://graphemica.com/categories/titlecase-letter), [“Modifier letter (Lm)”](http://graphemica.com/categories/modifier-letter), [“Other letter (Lo)”](http://graphemica.com/categories/other-letter), or [“Letter number (Nl)”](http://graphemica.com/categories/letter-number).
>
> The rest of the string can contain the same characters, plus any *U+200C zero width non-joiner* characters, *U+200D zero width joiner* characters, and characters in the Unicode categories [“Non-spacing mark (Mn)”](http://graphemica.com/unicode/categories/nonspacing-mark), [“Spacing combining mark (Mc)”](http://graphemica.com/categories/spacing-combining-mark), [“Decimal digit number (Nd)”](http://graphemica.com/categories/decimal-digit-number), or [“Connector punctuation (Pc)”](http://graphemica.com/categories/connector-punctuation).

For more information, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9337047/1216976), which contains the above and more.

Comment: great resource! but the regex is real killer!

Comment: By the same author as the linked answer: https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/javascript-identifier-regex

Comment: Oh so `some̵·booleanʔ` is a valid identifier, actually. Neat.